# Why has this question been closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[Which game is using the term "Butterfly Stroke"?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/24781/which-game-is-using-the-term-butterfly-stroke)

It asks about **one single** term used in a sport the OP doesn't (or didn't) know. Hence the question.

Yes, it's a bad question as it's easily googled for. But how can this question be fixed to address the close reason? It's only about a single term and more clarity than that? How's that even possible?

Answer (score -1):

When it was first asked, it was tagged with four different sports, seemingly at random. This makes it unclear what the asker is actually trying to do - do they mean which sports the term was first used in? Regularly used in? Only used in? A specific game in any of those sports? All of those sports?

When it was edited, it was done in a way that makes the question answer itself. *Meta* considerations are not an appropriate use of tags either. So it's now unclear (as pointed out in a comment) what additional information the question seeks that is not contained in it already.

---

Finally, the asker says they already found the answer to their question by using Google. Even if it was technically a clear question about a competitive sport, this is not the kind of question what Stack Exchange is for. We are not a human-powered manual search engine or a Google intermediary.

Comment: The question is very clear. *Where* is the term being used. Not first, not last, not regular... just where. Only because it's easy to google doesn't make it a close candidate. It's simply down vote and move on. And if you're unhappy with the tags - edit them.

Comment: *Where* is in neither the title (using "which game") not the body (using "what game"). If it's so clear that it's not even possible to interpret the question without changing it, in a way that significantly affects what answers apply to any correct interpretation, you've only made the point further.

Comment: Nonsense. Now you're just nitpicking. Where is x being used? = What/which game is using x? It's pretty common to have questions rephrased, especially those from non-natives. Now that seems to be an unsolvable problem for you?